# Example Wordpress content from github missing for juju charm

Tags: juju, wordpress

I'm looking into using the Wordpress JuJu charm but am blocked right from the get go because the link they give http://github.com/jujutools/wordpress-site for what a wordpress site should look like doesn't exist.

Does anybody know what the new repo is?  I've tried searching at github and on the juju site without any luck.

The setting in the charm that I'm referring to is:

> wp-content (string)
>   This is a full repository path to where the
>   WordPress wp-contents can be found. At this time Git, BZR, SVN, and HG
>   are supported. An example of what a wp-content repository should look
>   like can be found at http://github.com/jujutools/wordpress-site.

Comment: There's an example repository here: https://github.com/marcoceppi/wordpress-demo I'm not sure who changed the example URL, but as the maintainer of the charm it wasn't me

Comment: Thanks Marco.  If you put this as an answer, I'd select it.

Answer (score 1):

What it means is that the content you want as YOUR `wp-content` needs to be able to be found in a publicly accessible repository and this configuration field needs to have the full path to that. The url in question is only an example value.

Comment: I disagree with your interpretation of this sentence. "An example of what a wp-content repository should look like can be found at http://github.com/jujutools/wordpress-site."  but thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

> There's an example repository [here](http://github.com/marcoceppi/wordpress-demo). I'm not sure who changed the example URL, but as the maintainer of the charm it wasn't me.

[Marco Ceppi♦ on Jul 31 '14 at 14:59](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505018/example-wordpress-content-from-github-missing-for-juju-charm/571789#comment680259_505018)

Answer (score 0):

Marco Ceppi posted the correct link.

https://github.com/marcoceppi/wordpress-demo

Thanks.

Comment: So why did you repost it? This is not an answer... If you want to copy a comment into an answer you should a) make it community wiki, b) quote it and c) link to the comment. See my answer (below) http://askubuntu.com/a/571792/186134 for how to do it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @EvandroSilva It *does* answer the question, it's just not the best example answer in the world.

Comment: @Seth imho i think this should be a comment, not an actual answer

Comment: @EvandroSilva I know "link only answers" are highly discouraged here, but in this case it was a link to official documentation they were looking for so, like I said earlier, while not the best possible answer it *is* an answer.